# Symbol in Text section yet undefined

Tags: c++, linker, nm

I have built xerces on HP-UX using c++. It also builds some executables which link against libxerces-c-3.1.sl. While running any of them I was getting symbol not found error:

```
SHLIB_PATH=../lib ./DOMCount
/usr/lib/dld.sl: Unresolved symbol: _ZNK11xercesc_3_113XMLBigDecimal10getRawDataEv (data)  from /home/build/HP-UX/lib/libxerces-c-3.1.sl
[HP ARIES32]: Core file for 32-bit PA-RISC application
[HP ARIES32]:   /home/build/HP-UX/bin/DOMCount saved to /home/build/HP-UX/bin/core.DOMCount
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I executed nm command it shows the symbol as undefined. However I can see the xercesc_3_1::XMLBigDecimal::getRawData() in text section as well.

```
nm -pxAN libxerces-c-3.1.sl | c++filt | grep getRawData
../lib/libxerces-c-3.1.sl:0x002c2ac8 T  xercesc_3_1::XMLAbstractDoubleFloat::getRawData() const
../lib/libxerces-c-3.1.sl:0x002c5390 T  xercesc_3_1::XMLBigDecimal::getRawData() const
../lib/libxerces-c-3.1.sl:0x004818c4 T  xercesc_3_1::XMLDateTime::getRawData() const
../lib/libxerces-c-3.1.sl:0x00000000 U  xercesc_3_1::XMLBigDecimal::getRawData() const
../lib/libxerces-c-3.1.sl:0x002c2ab0 T  xercesc_3_1::XMLAbstractDoubleFloat::getRawData() const
../lib/libxerces-c-3.1.sl:0x002c9988 T  xercesc_3_1::XMLDateTime::getRawData() const
../lib/libxerces-c-3.1.sl:0x002c5378 T  xercesc_3_1::XMLBigDecimal::getRawData() const
../lib/libxerces-c-3.1.sl:0x002c99a0 T  xercesc_3_1::XMLDateTime::getRawData() const
```

Can somebody help me understand how can symbol be undefined if it is in text section? Or am I misunderstanding something?

**Edit**:
In the code I can see an inline function definition inside the code, so why symbol is not found is another issue:

```
inline XMLCh*  XMLBigDecimal::getRawData() const
{
    return fRawData;
}
```